# Perforce's p4 sync doesn't catch changes

Tags: synchronization, client, perforce

I have an odd issue of my `p4 sync <path>/...` always returns

```
- file(s) up-to-date.
```

This started happening intermittently about 2 weeks ago, then slowly progressed to 100% not working ie `p4 sync` does not pickup any changes.

If I run

```
p4 changes -m5
Enter password: 
User <p4user> logged in.
Change 1523039 on 2019/09/19 by *********************************************online fix read me info'
Change 1523038 on 2019/09/19 by *********************************************config ids to Part'
Change 1523037 on 2019/09/19 by **********************************************pending* 'Created item-definition cache f'
Change 1523036 on 2019/09/19 by ********************************************* '<saved by Perforce> '
Change 1523035 on 2019/09/19 by ********************************************* '<saved by Perforce> '
```

Ran `p4 sync <path>/...` and got the *files up to date* response.

I have performed the following steps a few times now

- cd
- p4 sync …#0
- rm -rf *
- p4 sync -f …

This then syncs all the files successfully. I am using this as part of my automated build pipeline so I can be having to do the above manually.

Incidentally, I did perform

```
export P4CONFIG=~/.p4settings; /bin/p4 login < ~/.p4p; p4 workspace
```

and validated the views all parameters are OK.

My build pipeline has worked for over a year. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you **literally** saying `p4 sync /...`, not `p4 sync //...`? That extra slash makes a **big** difference.

Comment: I have tried 
"p4 sync ..."  "p4 sync ...#head" "p4 sync <path>/..."

Comment: cd'ing into the appropriate dir of course

Comment: Per the answer, there wasn't really an answer here, so I am voting to close this as Typo/NotRepro.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly faster alternative to your `p4 sync -f` workaround is `p4 clean`.  This is still pretty slow compared to a normal sync, since it needs to checksum the entire workspace, but it's at least a bit faster than re-transferring all the files over the network.

As far as finding and fixing the root cause so you can just sync at full speed and with full confidence, here are some basic things to check up front:

1. What does `p4 have` show as being synced to the workspace?  Is it the head revisions, or are the revisions old?
2. If `p4 have` shows that you have old revisions but `p4 sync` doesn't want to update them, check `p4 opened` -- remember that `p4 sync` won't immediately update open files (it will instead schedule a `resolve` so you can merge the changes)

I'm going to proceed on the assumption that `p4 have` shows you already have the head revisions, and the issue isn't that the files are `opened`.

1. Are you ever using `p4 sync -k` or `p4 flush` to force an update of the have list without updating the workspace?  If so, your workspace is obviously going to be inconsistent afterwards; you probably don't want to use those commands.
2. Are you using the same client spec to sync multiple machines?  If so, they're sharing a have list, but not the physical workspace, so the machine where you didn't do the sync is going to be inconsistent with the have list.  **Do not share a client spec across multiple workspaces.**  The `Host` field in the client spec will help remind you not to do this, as long as you don't delete it or override `P4HOST`.

If you're not sure of the answers to those questions, you can check the server log to see which commands have been issued with this client spec.  You may also want to consider setting the client spec to `locked` to prevent mischievous usage that might break your build pipeline.

Comment: Hi.. so we use on p4 config per workspace. I never use _p4 sync -k_ or _p4 flush_. apologies I should have mentioned this earlier. this is our code (we use ansible): `- name: P4 sync latest CL for branch path
  shell: "p4 sync {{ p4_sync_path }}/..."
  environment:
    P4CONFIG: "{{ deploy_dir }}/.p4settings"
    PATH: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/opt/mono/bin:/opt/home/bin
  register: p4_sync_output
  when: cl_to_sync == "latest"
  changed_when: False`

Comment: we use the output of `p4_sync_output` to determine if we build or not. output doesnt end in _- file(s) up-to-date._ a build gets kicked off. I ran the `p4 have` and the latest version does show.

Comment: so you need to figure out at what point your `have` list got set to the head revisions.  **Does each config file have a unique value for P4CLIENT?**  I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to sharing client specs since that would be an easy way for your `have` list to get messed up without you doing anything actively.

Comment: heres the full logic (apologies for the formatting): `- name: P4 sync latest CL for branch path
  shell: "p4 sync {{ p4_sync_path }}/..."
  environment:
    P4CONFIG: "{{ deploy_dir }}/.p4settings"
    PATH: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/opt/mono/bin:/opt/home/bin
  register: p4_sync_output
  when: cl_to_sync == "latest"
  changed_when: False` `- name: Set flag if p4 workspace is already up to date
  set_fact:
    p4_ws_already_latest: True
  when: "p4_sync_output.stderr is defined and 'ile(s) up-to-date.' in p4_sync_output.stderr"`

Comment: `- include: roles/build_deploy/tasks/build.yml
when: p4_ws_already_latest is not defined or force_build == "True"`

Comment: I went and triple checked the p4 configs and we do not share work spaces across p4client.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: this is interesting your comment `If p4 have shows that you have old revisions but p4 sync doesn't want to update them, check p4 opened -- remember that p4 sync won't immediately update open files (it will instead schedule a resolve so you can merge the changes)` the user for this workspace makes no edits, only used for syncing files.... the scheduling a resolve is new to me

Comment: I appreciate the effort in your feedback, thanks for that. Ill go and chase the p4 administrators responses have been quite sparse so far. Thanks!

Comment: this is interesting your comment `If p4 have shows that you have old revisions but p4 sync doesn't want to update them, check p4 opened -- remember that p4 sync won't immediately update open files (it will instead schedule a resolve so you can merge the changes)` the user for this workspace makes no edits, only used for syncing files.... the scheduling a resolve is new to me...the files in question have been submitted and therefore are not in open state so I dont think this applies to us?

Comment: nope, that doesn't apply.  At this point I'd recommend going through the server log files to get a record of when the client has been synced.  The have list won't update all by itself, so *somebody* is syncing that client but the files aren't landing in your workspace.  (Or maybe you're syncing and then rolling back the contents of the workspace from a manual backup instead of syncing back to an older revision?)

Comment: I also might recommend posting on forums.perforce.com instead of here, because it's almost impossible to debug something in a SO comment thread.  I want to see some actual command output, config info, and log data, but it's not really feasible in this format.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, appreciate your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it. I couldn't find a solution, so created a new workspace and copied in the client configs and workspace views. Our builds are working now again.